# How to add list of time in mysql while we have n numbers of times are in 00:00:00 format

Tags: mysql, sql, time

How to add  list of time in mysql while we have n numbers of times are in 00:00:00 format

```
id   time
1    00:12:21
2    00:02:00
3    01:00:01
4    00:00:20
```

I tried

```
SELECT ADDTIME(time) 
from table 
where 1=1
```

but ADDTIME(time1,time2) take 2 parameters only

it add as ADDTIME(00:00:20,00:00:21) => 00:00:41

I want to add all the times as present in time column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timeSpent` ) ) ) AS timeSum  
FROM YourTableName
```